# JavaScript function for a scheduled event time with server time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, windows

This is my javascript code below for scheduled event time, however, I am not sure how to implement the `var HGEventTime` to be dynamic. What I mean is this: `HGEventTime` runs 3 times per day. First at `10:00`, second at `19:00` and third at `22:00`. Website is hosted on a Windows server, so somehow I must implement a check probably in php to get the server time and then compare it to one of the times. Also, I will have to add a function for a second event called HGWeekEventTime where it runs twice a day but only on Monday and Friday. I am not really good with JavaScript. All the help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var HGEventTime = "123123";

    var HGEventdays = Math.floor(HGEventTime / 86400);
    var HGEventhours = Math.floor((HGEventTime - (HGEventdays*86400)) / 3600);
    var HGEventmins = Math.floor((HGEventTime - (HGEventdays*86400 + HGEventhours*3600)) / 60);
    var HGEventsecs = Math.floor(HGEventTime % 60);


    var HGEventcounter = setInterval(HGEventTimer, 1000);

    function HGEventTimer()
    {
        HGEventsecs = HGEventsecs - 1;

        if(HGEventdays < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML = "The event already begun!";
            clearInterval(HGEventcounter);
            return;
        }
        if(HGEventhours < 0)
        {
            HGEventdays = HGEventdays - 1;
            HGEventhours = 23;
            HGEventmins = 59;
            HGEventsecs = 59;
            return;
        }
        if(HGEventmins < 0)
        {
            HGEventhours = HGEventhours - 1;
            HGEventmins = 59;
            HGEventsecs = 59;
            return;
        }
        if(HGEventsecs < 0)
        {
            HGEventmins = HGEventmins - 1;
            HGEventsecs = 59
            return;
        }

        if (HGEventdays == 0 && HGEventhours == 0 && HGEventmins < 10)
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").style.color = "red";

        if (HGEventsecs < 10 && HGEventmins < 10 && HGEventhours < 10)
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML=HGEventdays+":0"+HGEventhours+":0"+HGEventmins+":0"+HGEventsecs;
        else if (HGEventmins < 10 && HGEventhours < 10)
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML=HGEventdays+":0"+HGEventhours+":0"+HGEventmins+":"+HGEventsecs;
        else if (HGEventsecs < 10 && HGEventhours < 10)
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML=HGEventdays+":0"+HGEventhours+":"+HGEventmins+":0"+HGEventsecs;
        else if (HGEventsecs < 10 && HGEventmins < 10)
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML=HGEventdays+":"+HGEventhours+":0"+HGEventmins+":0"+HGEventsecs;
        else if (HGEventhours < 10)
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML=HGEventdays+":0"+HGEventhours+":"+HGEventmins+":"+HGEventsecs;
        else if (HGEventmins < 10)
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML=HGEventdays+":"+HGEventhours+":0"+HGEventmins+":"+HGEventsecs;        
        else if (HGEventsecs < 10)
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML=HGEventdays+":"+HGEventhours+":"+HGEventmins+":0"+HGEventsecs;
        else
            document.getElementById("HGEventTimer").innerHTML=HGEventdays+":"+HGEventhours+":"+HGEventmins+":"+HGEventsecs;
    }


</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript does not know about or talk to a server unless you use Ajax.

Comment: @Dave - I understand, so how to supply to the javascript `var HGEventTime = "123123";` the correct time left based on what is the current server time and what time left until one of the 3 events per day at `10:00`, at `19:00` and at `22:00`? Ofc, it will need to restart the timer after one of the events started until the next one.